# objective c (Firebase): child with custom ID gets overwritten

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made a function for creating a new child with ID being equal to a token I want to store.

**The code is:**

`FIRDatabaseReference* memberReference = [[[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Users/%@/DeviceTokens", userID]] child:token];`

The problem is that whenever a new token is created, it overwrites the old one, even if the new token is different from the token its overwriting.

Why is it doing this?

Edit - uploading the function itself

```
- (void)uploadDeviceTokenForUser:(NSString *)userID token:(NSString *)token {

    FIRDatabaseReference *tokenReference = [[[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Users/%@/DeviceTokens", userID]] child:token];
    [tokenReference setValue:@"0"];
}
```

The code is called from `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken {

    NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", fcmToken);
    [[ChatManager sharedManager] uploadDeviceTokenForUser:[PFUser currentUser].objectId token:fcmToken];
}
```

Comment: Show the function that isn't working as expected.

Comment: Done. I don't think it provides much additional insight though.